# I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml

I want save data from PHP to XML but i got this error.
I tried the  following code. I use this in other code where it works, but here it doesn't 
work. How can I sove this problem?

```
$logreport=simplexml_load_file('files/log_report.xml');
$login = $logreport->addChild('log');
$login->addAttribute('id', $_POST['username']);
$login->addChild('name', $_POST['password']);
$logreport->asXML('files/log_report.xml');
```

Comment: Is that file exited on the given path with read permission??

Comment: Try loading it with the absolute path, not the relative path